# Close modal bottom sheet after go back from other page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue with modal bottom sheet.
After I use Navigator.push to another page, the modal bottom sheet remain there when I go back.
I already try using `FocusScope.of(context).focusedChild.unfocus();` and `Navigator.pop(context);` still not helping.

Modal bottom sheet code:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                context: context,
                isScrollControlled: true,
                builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: AddTask(), //open statefull widget
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
```

Add Task code:

```
     Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          onTap: () async {
            FocusScope.of(context).focusedChild.unfocus();
            await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid, taskId: taskId)
                .updateTask(false, _titleValue, _notesValue,
                    UpdateChecklist().checklistInput, '', '', '');
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => TaskDetail(
                        uid: user.uid,
                        taskId: taskId,
                      )),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

is there any way to make the modal bottom sheet go back to unfocus when I return to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it solved by adding `then`.

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              onTap: () async {
                await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid, taskId: taskId)
                    .updateTask(false, _titleValue, _notesValue,
                        UpdateChecklist().checklistInput, '', '', '');
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => TaskDetail(
                            uid: user.uid,
                            taskId: taskId,
                          )),
                ).then((value) => Navigator.pop(context));
```

Answer (score 0):

closing showModalBottomSheet programmatically is done via

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Comment: I already tried using Navigator.pop(context); However, it is not going to the TaskDetail page. The screen stay on modal bottom sheet.

Comment: @Alamsyah: Are you launching new screen from your bottom sheet? and if yes the you want to hide the bottom sheet at that time?

Comment: @Alamsyah: Could you comment out DatabaseService and Navigator.push() code, just keep Navigator.pop()? then tell me if it hides bottom sheet

Comment: it works, but, I need to push to another page as well. I cannot put 2 navigator on the same function. The result will not go anywhere